# .slideToggle(); only one <ul> at a time

Tags: jquery

I know the solution to this is probably really easy, but my JavaScript/Jquery abilities are lacking.

I'd like to modify an expandable/collapsible list that uses .slideToggle() to expand a hidden list so that when a new list item is clicked, the previously clicked list item is closed.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkfdmpes/).

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myScript').remove();
        $('.mylist').columns({
            columns: 1
        });
        // 'hide' function is called on each of the 'ul' elements with the class 'guide_links'
        $('ul.guide_links').hide();
        // DOM insert a link element inside of each of the subject list items.
        $('li.subject_link').prepend('<a href="javascript://toggle guide links" class="toggle_button">+</a>');
        // enable toggle action on each Subject LI
        $('li.subject_link').bind("click", function () {
            // toggles text in the link between '+' and '-'.
            if ($(this).children('a.toggle_button').text() == '+') {
                $(this).children('a.toggle_button').text('-');
            } else {
                $(this).children('a.toggle_button').text('+');
            }
            // Toggle the child 'ul' element
            $(this).children('ul.guide_links').slideToggle("fast");
        });

        $('a.subject_link_a').contents().unwrap();
        $('a[href^="http://"]').not('a[href*=gusdecool]').attr('target', '_blank');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your click function to this:

```js
$('li.subject_link').bind("click", function () {
    $('a.toggle_button').text('+');
    $('ul.guide_links').hide();
    
    $(this).children('a.toggle_button').text('-');
    $(this).children('ul.guide_links').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

It closes all lists and changes all texts to '+'.
Than sets '-' for clicked item text and opens child list.

Comment: Worked perfect, I just changed $('ul.guide_links').hide("fast"); to get it to go slide smooth.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind the click event, you need to initialize the other list elements first:

```
....
$('li.subject_link').bind("click", function(){

    //initialize 
    $('ul a.toggle_button').text('-');
    $('ul ul.guide_links').slideUp("fast");

    // toggles text in the link between '+' and '-'.
    .......
```

Comment: As soon as I get enough rep you'll get an upvote, your solution worked perfect in the fiddle, but only worked in a single column out of three on our site.